# "No file" error when trying to upload files via the file manager

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager

I'm getting a "No file" error when trying to upload files via the native file manager. You can see the browser uploading the image but then you get the rather unhelpful red error message.

I was able to upload files no problem a few weeks ago and the only thing that's changed since then is upgrading to 2.5.5.

Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Uploading images via FTP and then synching the file upload directory via the CP works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try turning off the "Apply XSS Filtering to uploaded files?" setting under Admin > Security and Privacy > Security and Sessions.

I've seen that filtering reject uploads with unhelpful error messages before, especially if you're uploading a PDF or non-image.

Comment: Assuming you have no user generated content (perhaps only admins are uploading files), this is really a great solution (worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

Try reuploading the themes folder from the 2.5.5 install. It's possible there is new JS that didn't get updated.

Comment: No dice there, but uploading on my local install seems to work fine.

Comment: Sounds like an issue on the server or your configs. Check paths, check upload directory permissions, make sure temp directory isn't full or having issues, make sure member has permissions set to upload an image.